# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Parse

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, onbackpressed

I'm developing an app that uses Parse to store and retrieve some data. I followed the setup guide on the website but it´s crashing!

These are the files:

MainActivity.java:

```
package apps.XXXXXX.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.parse.Parse;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new Frag())
                    .commit();
        }

        // Enable Local Datastore.
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Frag.java

```
package apps.XXXXXX.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Frag extends Fragment {

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    String[] values = new String[5];
    FragmentActivity activity;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public static Frag newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Frag fragment = new Frag();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Frag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        activity = this.getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        values[0] = "laps";
        values[1] = "activeEvent";
        values[2] = "eventName";
        values[3] = "highlights";
        values[4] = "image";

        ParseHelper parseHelper = new ParseHelper("Event", "objectId", "XXXXXXX", values, activity);
        parseHelper.executeString();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

The app is able to retrieve data form Parse. But when I press the Back Button and go back to the app (icon or trough the recent apps) it's giving me this:

```
02-25 09:22:32.146    3295-3295/apps.xxxx.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: apps.xxxx.test, PID: 3295
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apps.xxxx.test/apps.xxxx.test.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context, String, String)`
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: `Parse#enableLocalDatastore(Context)` must be invoked before `Parse#initialize(Context, String, String)`
        at com.parse.Parse.enableLocalDatastore(Parse.java:102)
        at apps.xxxx.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution!

Just create a class named Application.java

```
package your.package.name;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class Application extends android.app.Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_CLIENT_KEY");
    }

}
```

Edit the application section on your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="your.package.name.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

That's it. That will maintain the Global Application State.

Comment: looking good , so far. I will let you know if I have problems with it. anyway I think you are missing super.onCreate(); and an @Override annotation  at the onCreate() of your Application class...